# How do I make a specific list out of a dictionary with multiple keys?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary in the form:

```
b = {(i1,k1,m1): l1, (i2,k2,m2): l2, (i3,k3,m3): l3, ...}
```

and i need the following list:

```
list = [(i1,k1,l1), (i2,k2,l2), ...].
```

(deleting m for each and adding l)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract keys using the dictionaries `keys` attribute and retrieve the value corresponding to each key in a list comprehension:

```
list = [(i,k,d[(i,k,m)]) for (i,k,m) in d.keys()]
```